# Is there a way to get a UIDatePickerView without the text?

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I want an empty date picker for my app's launch image.  Preferrably no text at all in any of the picker views.

Short of defining a custom UIPickerView to look that way, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in fact no. But this should be simple enough to do in any image editing program. Just copy and paste empty strips from left to right over the letters. I've done this with the Keyboard for my own launch image as well.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, the answer is "No".  What I did was setup a UIPickerView to look almost exactly the same.  But I think I like the image editing solution a little better.